# Running Ubuntu Touch Emulator failing

Tags: 15.10, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-emulator

I'm trying to install Ubuntu emulator on my Ubuntu 15.10 64bit system, but it won't run

I'm getting this error:

```
 * Setting up X socket directories...                                    [ OK ] 
[  133.338001] systemd-logind[953]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@32011.service
/lib/init/init-d-script: 12: /etc/rc2.d/S02whoopsie: -c: not found
basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

[Full log (Ubuntu Pastebin)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14630516/)

I'm using the NVIDIA binary driver:
[image]

Comment: What is an "Ubuntu emulator"? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: The *ubuntu-emulator* package, Ubuntu touch emulator

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg21226.html) the arm emulator is not currently in a stable state - it is slow and prone to locking up. They recommend using the i386 emulator instead.

It appears the `basename: missing operand` error itself is not critical. It is probably the next thing it's trying to do that is not succeeding, or stuck in an infinite loop.